# Memory leakage tool for C++ for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Can anyone suggest me good plugin for memory leakage which can be integrated in Visual Studio 2010 ? Any advice is good.

Comment: There is rational purify plus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using [Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/). It's intended for Visual C++ though.

Comment: "though"?
is not exactly what OP asked?

Comment: The question is tagged as c++. So I assume that he's looking for a memory leak detector for Visual C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [BoundsChecker](http://www.componentsource.com/products/devpartner-visual-c-boundschecker-suite-visual-studio-named-users/index.html) which can be integrated with Visual studio!

Answer (score 1):

You could do the followings:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
# define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC 1 // better in project file in DEBUG mode
# include <crtdbg.h>
# include <new>
# define malloc(size)       _malloc_dbg(size,_CLIENT_BLOCK,__FILE__,__LINE__)
# define realloc(addr,size) _realloc_dbg(addr,size,_CLIENT_BLOCK,__FILE__,__LINE__)
# define free(addr)         _free_dbg(addr,_CLIENT_BLOCK)

void * __stdcall operator new ( size_t size, const char * filename, int linenumber )
{
  void * tmp = _malloc_dbg( size, _CLIENT_BLOCK, filename, linenumber );
  if ( tmp == NULL )
    throw std::bad_alloc;
  return tmp;
}
void * __stdcall operator new [] ( size_t size, const char * filename, int linenumber )
{
  void * tmp = _malloc_dbg( size, _CLIENT_BLOCK, filename, linenumber );
  if ( tmp == NULL )
    throw std::bad_alloc;
  return tmp;
}
// If you need, you could implement the nothrow version of new operator, too.
void __stdcall operator delete( void *p, const char * filename, int linenumber )
{
  _free_dbg(p,_CLIENT_BLOCK)
}
void __stdcall operator delete[]( void *p, const char * filename, int linenumber )
{
  _free_dbg(p,_CLIENT_BLOCK)
}
void __stdcall operator delete( void *p )
{
  _free_dbg(p,_CLIENT_BLOCK)
}
void __stdcall operator delete[]( void *p )
{
  _free_dbg(p,_CLIENT_BLOCK)
}
// if there is MFC, you could use MFC style DEBUG_NEW
# ifdef DEBUG_NEW
#  define new DEBUG_NEW
# else
#  define DEBUG_NEW_HEAP new( __FILE__, __LINE__ )
#  define new DEBUG_NEW_HEAP
# endif
#endif
```

In this way you don't need profiler or any additional plugin, Visual Studio automatically collects the memory leaks for you (and Professional version is enough).